# Probability Calculation using combinations

Tags: probability, analysis

In a population of $250$ items, $20$ are defective. Suppose $4$ items are sampled at random, without replacement. 
a. What is the probability that the sample will consist of $4$ defective items?
Solution (don't know if it is correct or not): $P$($4$ defective) = $\dfrac{1}{\binom{20}{4}} = \dfrac{1}{4845}$

b. What is the probability that the sample will consist of $3$ or fewer defective items?
Solution (again, don't know if correct or not): $\dfrac{1}{\binom{20}{3}} + \dfrac{1}{\binom{20}{2}} + \dfrac{1}{\binom{20}{1}}$

c. What is the probability that the sample will consist of neither zero nor four defectives? (NO clue how to do this one)

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**First Question:** There are $\binom{250}{4}$ ways to choose $4$ items from $250$. All these choices  are *equally likely*.

There are $\binom{20}{4}$ ways to choose $4$ defectives. So the required probability is 
$$\frac{\binom{20}{4}}{\binom{250}{4}}.$$

**Second Question:** The answer is most easily found as $1$ minus the answer to the first.

**Third Question:** The simplest way is to first find the probability of $0$ **or** $4$ bad. (This is the *complement* of the event we are interested in.) The probability of $4$ bad has already been found. The probability of $4$ good is found in the same way, except that in the numerator we have $\binom{230}{4}$. So the probability of neither $0$ nor $4$ is 
$$1-\frac{\binom{20}{4}}{\binom{250}{4}}-\frac{\binom{230}{4}}{\binom{250}{4}}.$$

**Remark:** There are easier ways to solve these *particular* problems. We chose the approach ABOVE because it generalizes nicely to more complicated problems. But let's solve the first problem a simple way.

Imagine choosing one at a time. The probability the first is bad is $\frac{20}{250}$. **Given** the first was bad, the probability the second is bad is $\frac{19}{249}$. And given the first two are bad, the probability the third is bad is $\frac{18}{248}$. Continue. But there is only one more step. So the probability they are all bad is
$$\frac{20}{250}\cdot\frac{19}{249}\cdot\frac{18}{248}\cdot\frac{17}{247}.$$

Comment: So the correct answer to a) is 250C4 b) 20C4/250C4 and c) 1-(b) ?

Comment: No, the correct answer to (a) is $\binom{20}{4}/\binom{250}{4}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. You guys are life savers :D

Comment: Nice answer mane.

Comment: @user1819786: You are welcome, the whole idea is to be of help with the goal that after a while help will not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

You employ Hypergeometric Distribution for such problems:

a) $$\dfrac{\binom{230}{0} \binom{20}{4}}{\binom{250}{4}}$$

b) $$1-\dfrac{\binom{230}{0} \binom{20}{4}}{\binom{250}{4}}$$

c) $$1-\dfrac{\binom{230}{0} \binom{20}{4}}{\binom{250}{4}}-\dfrac{\binom{230}{4} \binom{20}{0}}{\binom{250}{4}}$$